# Calling a background image within the HTML for dynamic loading

Tags: html, css

I wanted to know if it is possible to have an image within the HTML document that behaves like a background image (currently done in CSS)?. The reason is so that the client can upload a background image via the CMS rather then myself having to manually do it for the client in CSS (which they do not have access to).

This is the effect I would like to create: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wabjyg

HTML

```
<div>
  <h1>An example of text over an image</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/1100/300/) no-repeat;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  }
```

One of doing it would be to have the background image as an inline style like this... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOrGYX - That way I can create a dynamic tag in the template which pulls the image path they upload in the CMS.

HTML

```
<div style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/1100/300')">
  <h1>An example of text over an image</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
}
```

Just wanted to know if there was another way of doing it without using inline styles within the HTML markup? Maybe tricking the IMG tag to behave like a background image?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to get an `img` to behave like a background image:

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

div {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

h1 {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  margin:0;
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  letter-spacing:-1px;
  text-align:center;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
   text-shadow:0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/1100/300">
  <h1>An example of text over an image</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this would have been ideal if I wasn't supporting IE, but it has to work down to IE9 at least, ideally IE8, so this is not an option, but still very useful. If no other solutions, I will mark this as the answer, as it has answered the question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, did not know that. Supporting IE9/8 can be a pain in the ***.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit Googling I found [this](https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/.) tutorial that offers a different solution.

You can put a extra stylesheet in your header, for example background.php

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/background.php' />
```

In that file you can set your variables and can use them in your stylesheet, like so.

```
 <?php
        header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");    

// DB Query here (or pass it with a function)

       $background = "/img/user/background/1.png";
    ?>

body, html { background: url(<?php echo $linkColor; ?>); }
```

Hope it helps.